# Renaming a GAS project in a copied spreadsheet using Drive API and Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I've got a script that copies a spreadsheet templeate that's got a GAS project bounded to it.
What I'm trying to do is change the name of the GAS project in the copied file.
I've already reviewed this anwser: [Rename appsscript project on duplication of spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409396/rename-appsscript-project-on-duplication-of-spreadsheet) but it doesen't seem to work for me.

I get the following error:

*Error GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.update failed with error: File not found: 1TKXKihWDHmPzasxFZH_-6OHDezdEFgiSfuQCcETJ3XYWBCO2kKNaa*

So it seems that it's unable to find the project, maybe it has to do with all the files being in a Shared Drive?

**Here is the code:**

```
function changeNameScript_returnsID(name_File, file, scriptID, sheetID ,year, name_Building, YearFolder) {
 
 //renames the script, copies the file in the desired folder and returns the id of the new file

  var originalGASProjectName = "Script Template" + name_Building;  // Please set the original project name of container-bound script ID of the template Spreadsheet.
  var newGASProjectName = "Script " + name_Building+ " " + year; // Please set the new GAS project name.

  // Rename to new project name.
  Drive.Files.update({title: newGASProjectName},scriptID);

  //makes a copy of the template in the desired folder, renames it and saves the ID of the file
  var id_newFile = file.makeCopy(name_File, YearFolder).getId();

  // Rename to original project name.
  Drive.Files.update({title: originalGASProjectName}, scriptID);
  return id_newFile
}
```

The error ocurs in:
`Drive.Files.update({title: newGASProjectName}, scriptID);`

**Attempt at using supportsAllDrives: true**

```
function canviarNomScript_retornaID(name_File, file, scriptID,year, name_Building, yearFolder) {
  //de StackOverflow modificada, canvia el nom del Script, copia l'arxiu on toca i retorna la ID de l'arxiu
  //link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409396/rename-appsscript-project-on-duplication-of-spreadsheet

  var originalGASProjectName = "Script Plantilla " + name_Building;  // Please set the original project name of container-bound script ID of the template Spreadsheet.
  var newGASProjectName = "Script " + name_Building + " " + year; // Please set the new GAS project name.

  // Rename to new project name.
  Drive.Files.update({title: newGASProjectName},scriptID,{supportsAllDrives: true });
 
  //Copies the file and gets the ID
  var id_newFile = file.makeCopy(name_File, yearFolder).getId();

  // Rename to original project name.
  Drive.Files.update({title: originalGASProjectName},scriptID,{supportsAllDrives: true });
  return id_newFile
```

**Error:** Exception: The mediaData parameter only supports Blob types for upload.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. If you want to use `supportsAllDrives` with `Drive.Files.update`, please modify it to `Drive.Files.update({title: newGASProjectName}, null, {supportsAllDrives: true})`. But, in your script, if `scriptID` is the script ID of the Google Apps Script project, an error occurs at `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID)`. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! I've already taken care of the `var ss`, it was a remnant of your code from the other post. So, I've got a question, how do you indicate which script is to be renamed with the modification you are proposing? I can't seem to get it working too. Sorry, I'm pretty new to GAS. Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `So, I've got a question, how do you indicate which script is to be renamed with the modification you are proposing? I can't seem to get it working too.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I messed up posting the code. Now it should be good. In summary, I've tried using your code the way it was intended in the last post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409396/rename-appsscript-project-on-duplication-of-spreadsheet?noredirect=1&lq=1). The problems happens in: `Drive.Files.update({title: newGASProjectName},scriptID);` Where it isn't able to find the script. I've tried using the argument `supportsAllDrives: true` because I read somewhere that if the file is in a shared Drive it doesn't work, but I don't know the syntax for `Drive.Files` Many thanks!!

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you provide your script of `I've tried using the argument supportsAllDrives: true`? Unfortunately, in your showing script, `supportsAllDrives: true` is not used. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike feel free to ask if you don't understand me, English isn't my first language either, and I've got to get better at explaining myself ahahah, Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @Tanaike I've uploaded the code at the post, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize. I noticed that my 1st comment was not correct. In this case, please modify to `Drive.Files.update({ title: newGASProjectName }, scriptID, null, { supportsAllDrives: true })` and test it again. The 2nd and 3rd arguments are `scriptID, null`. And, 4th argument is `{ supportsAllDrives: true }`.

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you so much!! I was banging my head for 2 days with this problem, I couldn't find the right syntax. Have a great day Tanaike! You are a savior.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the modification, I noticed that `Drive.Files.patch({ title: newGASProjectName }, scriptID, { supportsAllDrives: true })` might be able to be also used. And, I thought that this information might be useful for other users. So, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
Drive.Files.update({title: newGASProjectName},scriptID,{supportsAllDrives: true });
```

#### To:

```
Drive.Files.update({ title: newGASProjectName }, scriptID, null, { supportsAllDrives: true });
```

or, in your situation, the file content is null. So, the following modification might be able to be used.

```
Drive.Files.patch({ title: newGASProjectName }, scriptID, { supportsAllDrives: true });
```

- The arguments of `Drive.Files.update` are `update(resource: Drive_v2.Drive.V2.Schema.File, fileId: string, mediaData: Blob, optionalArgs: Object)`.
- The arguments of `Drive.Files.patch` are `patch(resource: Drive_v2.Drive.V2.Schema.File, fileId: string, optionalArgs: Object)`.
- In the case of `supportsAllDrives`, please include it in the query parameter. In this case, please include it as `optionalArgs` of Drive API at Advanced Google services.

#### References:

- [Method: files.update of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/files/update)
- [Method: files.patch of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/files/patch)