Change the script name with GAS
When I copy my Spreadsheet file with Drive ( DriveApp.getFileById(template).makeCopy(name, folder) ), the script name is unchanged.  How can I change the script name with Google App Script?
Read the documentation and go to Google.

If my understanding of script name of the script name is unchanged is correct, I guessed that this thread might be an answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60409396

I think you could use the App Script API, projects: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects
As the resource project includes "parentId": string, which would be here the id of the newly created spreadsheet. Then by getting the scriptId it might be possible to rename it
But I've never done it, this is only a suggestion
